# What are some of the most "shining" examples of usage of LaTeX

Tags: typography

I was wondering what are the "creative limits" of LaTeX. I've seen many beautifully typeset documents, books, scientific papers, which are of the highest quality, both aesthetically and in respect to content. After all, LaTeX **is** the best typesetting system in my opinion — overwhelming amount of amazing works written in it is therefore no surprise. I've even seen it put to work when constructing *facsimile* of a medieval manuscript.

But I am convinced I haven't seen it all. Please link me some of the best works ('best' as in the best overall aesthetics, "cleaneness" of the final product) done with this superb piece of software. As an example of a brilliant scientific paper, I must link [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06811.pdf) paper — the amount of attention to detail and hard work that went into this article is astonishing (and further demonstrated the power of [`tqft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tqft) package). Of course I accept literary works typeset with LaTeX with open arms as well. Thank you for your suggestions in advance.